# How can I use describe in a loop?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai

I'm trying to write test cases that test a chatbot and I need to check many things in `it` blocks on every response. So the flow right now is that I send many messages and I'm trying to have a describe statement inside the forEach loop but for some reason this isn't working. None of the tests in the `it` blocks are running.

```
const body = ['hi', 'transfer 20 sms', 'no', 'no', 'first one', 'first one']

describe('API', () => {
      describe('Basic flow', () => {
        body.forEach((v, i) => {
          describe(`Should get response for message #${i + 1}`, () => {
            return agent.post('/watson/send').send({
              'content': {
                'userInput': v,
                'userDial': '123456'
              }
            }).then(response => {
              it('Body should exist', done => {
                // this part doesnt work
                const { body } = response
                const { text } = response.body.reply
                expect(_.isEmpty(body)).to.equal(false)
                done()
              })
            })
          })
        })
      })
    })
```

My understanding is that this doesn't work because mocha doesn't find `it` blocks inside promises. I can't figure out how to restructure this so as to have multiple `it` blocks that test the same result of the API.

Comment: you are calling API, you have to call this API's controller simply mock the body and response

Comment: @muhammadAli that wont work because I have a session object between requests that the controller uses

Comment: add catch body to find any error, there any logs on this controller?

Comment: I checked. Nothing is logged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`describe` expects `it` block, you're writing code in it directly. Try to use hooks to execute the API and then `test` its response.

```
describe('Should get response for message', function () {

    let _response;

    // before hook
    before(function () {

        return agent.post('/watson/send').send({
            'content': {
                'userInput': v,
                'userDial': '123456'
            }
        }).then(response => {
            _response = response;
            done();
        })
    });

    // test cases
    it('Body should exist', done => {
        // this part doesnt work
        const { body } = _response
        const { text } = _response.body.reply
        expect(_.isEmpty(body)).to.equal(false)
        done()
    })
});
```

Comment: I tried doing this but it won't work because I'm calling the API multiple times (say 7 times), the before hook here would only be called once

Comment: I solved my issue by adding the loop before the `before` block in your code

Comment: `before` hook will always run inside `describe`. So my idea was to put this entire code snippet I shared inside your loop. You solved it anyway, so no point in explanation now :)